Rational isogenies of prime degree $p\in\{11,17,19,37,43,67,163\}$
Let $p\in\{11,17,19,37,43,67,163\}$ be a prime number. In [1], B. Mazur proves that there are only finite number of elliptic curves $E$ [over $\mathbb{Q}$] having an isogeny of degree $p$.
Here is my question:

Is there a list of the $j$-invariant $j(E)$ for all the elliptic curves $E$ [over $\mathbb{Q}$] having an isogeny of degree $p$?

I am interested in the case where $j(E)$ is not an integer, or $j(E)$ is of the form $2^a3^b$, so we can only consider my question in this special case.
Many thanks.
[1]: Mazur, B. "Rational isogenies of prime degree", Inventiones Mathematicae, 1978

143 = 11 * 13  perhaps you mean 163   https://oeis.org/A003173

@WillJagy Thank you! Sorry for my error, and I will change "143" into "163".

Five of these $j(E)$ values, one each for $p=11,19,43,67,163$,
are for curves $E$ with complex multiplication by the ring of integers
in the quadratic field of discriminant $-p$.  All of them are integral,
and none is of the form $2^a 3^b$ though two are $-2^a 3^b$, for $p=11$
(with $j = -2^{15}$) and $p=19$ (with $j = -2^{15} 3^3$).
There is another $11$-isogenous pair of rational $j$-invariants,
but those are $-11^2$ and $-11 \cdot 131^3$, so not within your scope; see
https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/121/a
(121.b is the CM case).
For $p=17$ these are the curves in LMFDB isogeny class 14450.b
https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/14450/b,
with $j=-297756989/2 = -17^2 101^3/2$ and
$-882216989/131072 = -17 \cdot 373^3 / 2^{17}$
(each with with several quadratic twists of the same conductor).
Finally, for $p=37$ the $j$-invariants are integral and not $\{2,3\}$-smooth:
$9317 = -7 \cdot 11^3$ and $-162677523113838677 = -7 \cdot 137^3 2083^3$,
as in isogeny class 1225.b https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1225/b.
All this has been known for some 50 years(!), see the "Remarks on isogenies" in
Modular Forms in One Variable IV, Springer LNM 476 (1975).
